# Set default Language Enviroment in Emacs

Tags: perl, emacs

I am writing a Perl program in GNU emacs without the file extension .pl or .pm. Is there a way I can set the language environment to Perl without having to change the file extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the mode:

```
M-x perl-mode
```

Comment: I would rather have M-x cperl-mode

Answer (score 5):

Put the comment

```
# -*- perl -*-
```

in the first (or second if you have the interpreter in the first line) line  of your file. If you do so it will open in perl mode next time you open it.

Answer (score 3):

You can with the following,

```
  (setq auto-mode-alist
        (append '(("\\.pl$"       . perl-mode)
                  ("\\.pm$"       . perl-mode)) auto-mode-alist))
```

Comment: Always assuming there is actually an extension in use which can safely be substituted into that code. FWIW, I'd be more inclined to write that as `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.\\(pl\\|pm\\)\\'" . perl-mode))`